# Clocktable grouped by category instead of by file

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I'd like to have a `clocktable` report which groups TODOs by their `CATEGORY` property instead of by file. As an example, this is my current `clocktable` report:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope cashpw/org-clock--agenda-with-archives :block "2023-11-13" :narrow 100 :fileskip0 t :filetitle t :properties ("CATEGORY")
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-11-13 Mon 20:04], for Monday, November 13, 2023.
|                          |                | <100>                                     |        |
| File                     | CATEGORY       | Headline                                  |   Time |
|--------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
|                          | ALL            | *Total time*                              | *4:10* |
|--------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Personal TODOs           |                | *File time*                               | *4:01* |
|                          | Personal TODOs | Personal email                            |   0:01 |
|                          | Study          | Flashcards                                |   0:23 |
|                          | Food           | Lunch                                     |   0:20 |
|                          | Food           | Dinner                                    |   0:20 |
|                          | Fitness        | Walk (evening)                            |   0:47 |
|                          | Fitness        | Stretch 1                                 |   0:16 |
|                          | Fitness        | Stretch 2                                 |   0:14 |
|                          | Health         | Brush teeth (morning)                     |   0:03 |
|                          | Fitness        | Shoulders                                 |   1:09 |
|--------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Personal TODOs (archive) |                | *File time*                               | *0:09* |
|                          | Personal TODOs | Confirm mortgage payment went through     |   0:03 |
|                          | Personal TODOs | Confirm credit card payments went through |   0:04 |
#+END:
```

I'd like to group the items by category --- ignoring file boundaries --- like this:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope cashpw/org-clock--agenda-with-archives :block "2023-11-13" :narrow 100 :fileskip0 t :filetitle t :properties ("CATEGORY")
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-11-13 Mon 20:04], for Monday, November 13, 2023.
|                | <100>                                     |        |
| Category       | Headline                                  |   Time |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
|                | *Total time*                              | *4:10* |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Personal TODOs | *Category time*                           | *X:XX* |
|                | Personal email                            |   0:01 |
|                | Confirm mortgage payment went through     |   0:03 |
|                | Confirm credit card payments went through |   0:04 |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Study          | *Category time*                           | *X:XX* |
|                | Flashcards                                |   0:23 |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Food           | *Category time*                           | *X:XX* |
|                | Lunch                                     |   0:20 |
|                | Dinner                                    |   0:20 |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Fitness        | *Category time*                           | *X:XX* |
|                | Walk (evening)                            |   0:47 |
|                | Stretch 1                                 |   0:16 |
|                | Stretch 2                                 |   0:14 |
|                | Shoulders                                 |   1:09 |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
| Health         | *Category time*                           | *X:XX* |
|                | Brush teeth (morning)                     |   0:03 |
|----------------+-------------------------------------------+--------|
#+END:
```

**What I've tried so far**

1. Reviewed the [docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html)
2. [`private/clocktable-formatter-group-by-prop`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48007/37010)

   Unfortunately this solution collapses the "Headline" column.

   ```
   #+BEGIN: clocktable :scope cashpw/org-clock--agenda-with-archives :block "2023-11-13" :narrow 200 :fileskip0 t :filetitle t :properties ("CATEGORY") :formatter cashpw/clocktable-formatter-group-by-prop :hidefiles t
   #+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-11-13 Mon 20:12], for Monday, November 13, 2023.
   | <200>          |        |
   | Headline       |   Time |
   |----------------+--------|
   | *Total time*   | *4:10* |
   |----------------+--------|
   | Fitness        |   2:26 |
   | Food           |   0:27 |
   | Health         |   0:03 |
   | Personal TODOs |   0:45 |
   | Pet            |   0:06 |
   | Study          |   0:23 |
   #+END:
   ```
3. [`org-dblock-write:clocktable-by-tag`](https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/5899058)

   This is the most promising. I'll need to fix up the functions since `:tags` changed and also switch from checking tags to checking categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've extended [ffevotte's `clocktable-by-tag` gist](https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/5899058) and published it as a repo on Github: **[cashpw/clocktable-by-tag](https://github.com/cashpw/clocktable-by-tag)**. I've included the full script below in case this link ever expires.

An example of the clocktable this generates:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable-by-tag :files-fn cashpw/agenda-with-archives :block "2023-11-13" :maxlevel 5
|         |                                           |      <r> |      |
| Tag     | Headline                                  | Time     |      |
|---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------|
|         | All *Total time*                          |   *4:13* |      |
|---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------|
| finance | *Tag time*                                |   *0:07* |      |
|         | Confirm mortgage payment went through     |          | 0:03 |
|         | Confirm credit card payments went through |          | 0:04 |
|---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------|
| health  | *Tag time*                                |   *1:42* |      |
|         | Stretch 1                                 |          | 0:16 |
|         | Stretch 2                                 |          | 0:14 |
|         | Brush teeth (morning)                     |          | 0:03 |
|         | Shoulders                                 |          | 1:09 |
|---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------|
| study   | *Tag time*                                |   *0:23* |      |
|         | Flashcards                                |          | 0:23 |
|---------+-------------------------------------------+----------+------|
| nil     | *Tag time*                                |   *0:48* |      |
|         | Personal email                            |          | 0:01 |
|         | Walk (evening)                            |          | 0:47 |
#+END:
```

```lisp
(require 'org-clock)
(require 's)

(defun clocktable-by-tag--shift-cell (n)
  (let ((str ""))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (setq str (concat str "| ")))
    str))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--get-clock-data (files params)
  "Return a list of all clock table data entries from FILES.

- PARAMS is a plist; see `org-clock-get-table-data'"
  (seq-reduce (lambda (all-clock-data file)
                (let* ((clock-data (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
                                     (org-clock-get-table-data (buffer-name)
                                                               params))))
                  (cl-destructuring-bind (_ total-minutes entries) clock-data
                    (if (> total-minutes 0)
                        (append all-clock-data
                                entries)
                      all-clock-data)
                    )))
              files
              '()))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--insert-row (tag entries)
  "Insert a row of ENTRIES for TAG.

- ENTRIES: List of entries with TAG; see `org-clock-get-table-data'"
  (insert "|--\n")
  (insert (s-lex-format "| ${tag} | *Tag time* |\n"))
  (let ((total 0))
    (dolist (entry entries)
      (cl-destructuring-bind (level headline _ _ minutes _) entry
        (setq total (+ total minutes))
        (let ((indent (org-clocktable-indent-string level))
              (shift-cell (clocktable-by-tag--shift-cell level))
              (duration (org-duration-from-minutes minutes)))
          (insert (s-lex-format "| |${indent}${headline} | ${shift-cell} ${duration} |\n")))))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((duration (org-duration-from-minutes total)))
        (re-search-backward "*Tag time*")
        (org-table-next-field)
        (org-table-blank-field)
        (insert (s-lex-format "*${duration}*")))))
  (org-table-align))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--get-tags (clock-data-entries)
  "Return unique list of tags within CLOCK-DATA-ENTRIES.

This function expects output in the form of a list of entries from `org-clock-get-table-data'."
  (seq-uniq
   (seq-reduce
    (lambda (tags-with-duplicates entry)
      (append tags-with-duplicates
              (nth 2 entry)))
    clock-data-entries
    '())))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--get-entries-by-tag-hash (entries)
  "Build a hash table of ENTRIES indexed by their first tag."
  (let ((entry-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (dolist (entry entries)
      (let* ((tags (nth 2 entry))
             (tag (nth 0 tags))
             (entries (gethash tag
                               entry-hash)))
        (puthash tag
                 (append entries
                         `(,entry))
                 entry-hash)))
    entry-hash))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--sum-durations (clock-data)
  "Return the total minutes logged for all entries in CLOCK-DATA."
  (seq-reduce (lambda (total-minutes entry)
                (cl-destructuring-bind (_ _ _ _ minutes _) entry
                  (setq total-minutes (+ total-minutes minutes))))
              clock-data
              0))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--get-files (params)
  "Return list of files from which to construct clocktable.

See `org-dblock-write:clocktable' for information on PARAMS.

Users can provide files in two ways:

1. ':files': A list file paths
2. ':files-fn': A function which is called without arguments and should return a list of file paths

If both are provided, ':files' is used."
  (let ((files-fn (plist-get params :files-fn))
        (files (plist-get params :files)))
    (when (and (not files-fn)
               (not files))
      (error "ERROR [clocktable-by-tag] You must provide either :files-fn or :files as parameters."))
    (or files
        (funcall files-fn))))

(defun clocktable-by-tag--insert-table-headings ()
  "Insert the initial table headings."
  (insert "| | | <r> |\n")
  (insert "| Tag | Headline | Time |\n")
  (insert "|--\n")
  (insert "| | All *Total time* | \n"))

(defun org-dblock-write:clocktable-by-tag (params)
  "Create a clocktable grouped by tags. Only look at first tag on each headline.

- PARAMS: See `org-dblock-write:clocktable'"
  (clocktable-by-tag--insert-table-headings)
  ;; We can't sort by tags unless we collect the tags
  (plist-put params :tags t)
  (let* ((files (clocktable-by-tag--get-files params))
         (clock-data (clocktable-by-tag--get-clock-data files
                                                        params))
         (entries-hash (clocktable-by-tag--get-entries-by-tag-hash clock-data))
         (tags (hash-table-keys entries-hash)))
    (dolist (tag tags)
      (clocktable-by-tag--insert-row tag
                                     (gethash tag entries-hash)))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((duration (org-duration-from-minutes (clocktable-by-tag--sum-durations clock-data))))
        (re-search-backward "*Total time*")
        (org-table-next-field)
        (org-table-blank-field)
        (insert (s-lex-format "*${duration}*"))
        (org-table-align)))))
```

Comment: I've extended the answer to include the source code and a usage example.

Comment: Thank you. That will help others.