# Is it possible to remove '\emsp' from clock report but preserve indentation?

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to replace '\emsp' with just plain spaces?

I.e,
In Clock reports, there are a lot of these '\emsp's. (See example below.)

I'm able to get rid of them by setting ':indent nil'. But this removes all indent altogether, which is undersirable. I can also get rid of them if I export things. But in the Agenda view I don't export reports and the \emsp's are just a visual distraction.

So far I was able to remove 'TODO' keywords via formatter [as described here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8228/remove-task-state-keywords-todo-done-from-clocktable-reports). But the formatter doesn't seem to see the '\emsp' and can't remove them. It kinda seems like they are added after.

```
|-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------|
| dev.org   | *File time*                                                       | *9:54*  |      |
|           | Dev                                                               | 9:54    |      |
|           | \emsp Configure VMs for testing [[elisp:(my/goto-parent)][parent]]                            |         | 5:03 |
|           | \emsp test if DND works in outline view in Mars (4.5) Build id: I20150217-0800 has outline view fixed (RHBZ#1012336). |         | 0:16 |
|           | \emsp GtkMenuItem directly instead of GtkImageMenuItem            |         | 1:28 |
|           | \emsp Bug 459487 - [GTK] Replace deprecated gtk_arrow_* with gtk_image |         | 1:31 |
|           | \emsp General                                                     |         | 1:36 |
```

Comment: Boutros' answer is correct, just be sure not to put it in a file called `org-table.el`, or your tables will explode.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a bug, IMO. Someone complained that the old indentation markers upset table layout in latex output so [someone replaced them](http://orgmode.org/w/org-mode.git?p=org-mode.git;a=commitdiff;h=bacfe5b4f7244eaf151f4e26a1d94dd8f66c1d19) with these latex instruction. Now of course it is a mess on screen.

I thought the new `prettify-symbols-mode` might be a handy way to switch out the `\emsp` for something else, but that can only replace with a single character and it upsets the layout of the table due to the changing width.

So there's nothing for it but to redefine the indentation code:

```
(defun my-org-clocktable-indent-string (level)
  (if (= level 1)
      ""
    (let ((str "^"))
      (while (> level 2)
        (setq level (1- level)
              str (concat str "--")))
      (concat str "-> "))))

(advice-add 'org-clocktable-indent-string :override #'my-org-clocktable-indent-string)
```

Change the indent markers to taste.

Comment: Too bad about the inconsitencies. It would be nice to have it fixed someday. The function above does fix things for me, thank you for posting.

Comment: It looks like I need emacs 24.4 to get this working. Le me upgrading from Fedora 20 to 21.

Comment: Works in Emacs 24.4

Comment: this is basically fixed in org-mode 8.3, so you can reuse that function instead: http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-clock.el#n2685

Comment: I’m using this with ╰ as initial marker and ─ instead of dashes (M-x insert-char BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT ARC UP AND RIGHT and BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL). It looks pretty good - thank you! `╰─> E-Mails lesen`

Answer (score 4):

The manual on [Special Symbols](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) says

> If you would like to see entities displayed as UTF-8 characters, use
>   the following command:
>
> C-c C-x \
>
> Toggle display of entities as UTF-8 characters. This does not change the buffer content which remains plain ASCII, but it overlays
>   the UTF-8 character for display purposes only.
>
> You can turn this on by default by setting the variable `org-pretty-entities`, or on a per-file base with the option `#+STARTUP: entitiespretty`.

Comment: Can I thank myself for posting this! I needed it 6 months later :P